# How can I loop this javascript function to remove redundant code?

Tags: javascript, loops, attributes, display

I have multiple different divs that each represent an item. I am using data attributes to assign a start date and end date to each. Then I have a function written to check if the current date is within this range. If it is, then I have more code that will add display:block to each div. For each div I have a separate lines of code that I am trying to figure out how to rewrite so that it loops. I want to have as many divs (items) as needed without having to add new code for each specific one. What I have is functioning but very redundant and cumbersome to keep up with.

HTML:

```
<!--Class A-->
   <div id="Class-A" class="col-12" data-class-start="1/1/2022" data-class-end="4/23/2022">
      <h1>Example</h1>
   </div>

<!--Class B-->
   <div id="Class-B" class="col-12" data-class-start="2/1/2022" data-class-end="4/23/2022">
      <h1>Example</h1>
   </div>

<!--Class C-->
   <div id="Class-C" class="col-12" data-class-start="3/1/2022" data-class-end="4/23/2022">
      <h1>Example</h1>
   </div>
```

JS:

```
/*--Class A--*/
var startA = document.getElementById("Class-A").getAttribute("data-class-start");
var endA = document.getElementById("Class-A").getAttribute("data-class-end");
if(dateCheck(startA, endA, new Date())) {
    document.getElementById("Class-A").style.display = "block";
  }

/*--Class B--*/
var startB = document.getElementById("Class-B").getAttribute("data-class-start");
var endB = document.getElementById("Class-B").getAttribute("data-class-end");
if(dateCheck(startB, endB, new Date())) {
    document.getElementById("Class-B").style.display = "block";
  }

/*--Class C--*/
var startC = document.getElementById("Class-C").getAttribute("data-class-start");
var endC = document.getElementById("Class-C").getAttribute("data-class-end");
if(dateCheck(startC, endC, new Date())) {
    document.getElementById("Class-C").style.display = "block";
  }

/*---Date Check Function--*/
function dateCheck(from,to,check) {

    var sDate,eDate,cDate;
    sDate = Date.parse(from);
    eDate = Date.parse(to);
    cDate = Date.parse(check);

    if((cDate <= eDate && cDate >= sDate)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them all a class in common - if `col-12` isn't used elsewhere, you can use that. Then just iterate over all elements matching that class.

The third parameter doesn't come from information outside the function, so it isn't needed.

```
for (const elm of document.querySelectorAll('.col-12')) {
    if (dateCheck(elm.dataset.classStart, elm.dataset.classEnd)) {
        elm.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

function dateCheck(from, to) {
    const cDate = new Date();
    const sDate = Date.parse(from);
    const eDate = Date.parse(to);
    return cDate <= eDate && cDate >= sDate;
}
```